# Freezing command-line build of a .NET MAUI Blazor App

Tags: android, .net, maui, maui-blazor

I'm using VS 2022 Preview 5 together with Maui Preview 9 and .NET 6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57

With that, I'm using the new project template ".NET MAUI Blazor App", where MAUI hosts a WebView in which Blazor is running. This enables building hybrid Blazor Apps cross-platform.

[image: Project Template Name]

Simply starting with the newly scaffolded project off the shelf, I can use Visual Studio to compile and run on Windows Desktop, Android Emulator and my physical Android device. So far, so shiny.

My goal is to figure out how to build for Android on the command line, however, to be able to set up a CI pipeline for those builds. So I thought I'd start by looking for the `*-signed.apk` that VS produces while building, and as a first test deploy that to the emulator by running `adb install path/to/myproject-signed.apk`

Here's the catch: This apk simply leaves the emulator hanging with the default .NET splash screen for these applications.

[image]

My question is: Which command should I issue on the command-line to generate an apk that works on the mobile device? I tried the following two options:

- `dotnet build -f net6.0-android` creates the same hanging application when installed via `adb`
- `dotnet build -c Release -f net6.0-android` yields a bigger apk, but the application crashes during startup

Comment: This issue is related to MAUI. You could post in GutHub.  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT - I also believe it has sth to do with MAUI, I just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook sth obvious before posting it as an issue there. Since VS can produce a working APK, there *must* be a way to produce one on the cli, too, right?